# Conditional operator "?:" in C++

Tags: c++, ternary-operator

Why this statement :

```
int a = 7, b = 8, c = 0;
c = b > a? a > b? a++: b++: a++ ? b++:a--;
cout << c;
```

is not equal to :

```
int a = 7, b = 8, c = 0;
c = (b > a? (a > b? a++: b++): a++)? b++: a--;
cout << c;
```

and is equal to :

```
int a = 7, b = 8, c = 0;
c = b > a? (a > b? a++: b++): (a++? b++: a--);
cout << c;
```

Please give me some reason. Why ?

Comment: If it's homework, please tag it as so.

Comment: Its all in the parenthesis. Pay attention to them, and you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: You mean equivalent, not equal.

Comment: I hope you're not really writing code like this.

Comment: oh no... It's not a homework!

Comment: @Melik4: If this isn't an academic exercise, then you need to start the refactoring process immediately (i.e. by writing unit tests).  The code tests for `a>b` after it is already known that `b>a`, which is completely useless.

Comment: @Ben Voigt, !(a > b) doesn't mean  b>a because is possible to have a = b.

Comment: @Saeed: Reread my comment (and the code) VERY carefully.  `b>a` implies `!(a<b)`, the first `a++` is unreachable.

Comment: oops, my most recent comment has a typo.  `b>a` implies `!(a>b)`, so the first `a++` is unreachable.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: It's not a homework or sth like this. It's about my pry in a book... and now I know that the book has some mistakes . I'm taking the following interesting to find out the problems... just it! but what do you mean? I'm not a perfect programmer... I'm just a starter... and so I like to go and think about some questions like this... can you help me to improve? plz...!

Comment: @Melik: ok, so it is an academic exercise but for self learning, not for class.  Nothing wrong with that.  Now, do you see why one of the nested ternary operators is useless, because one of the paths can't ever be taken?

Comment: @Melik: Would you be able to rewrite this with `if` statements?  The unreachable path might be easier to see that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put it on multiple lines to see the differences :

```
c = b>a        // true
    ? a>b      // false
      ? a++
      : b++    // b is incremted = 9; c = 8 (post increment)
    : a++ 
      ? b++
      : a--;
```

is not equal to :

```
c = ( b>a     // true
    ? ( a>b   // false
      ? a++
      : b++ ) // b is incremted = 9
    : a++ )   // a = 7 (= 8 after post increment), thus true
    ? b++     // ... b is incremented = 10, c = 9 (post increment)
    : a--;
```

and is equal to :

```
c = b>a         // true
    ? ( a>b     // false
      ? a++
      : b++ )   // b is incremnted = 9, c = 8 (post increment)
    : ( a++     
        ? b++   
        : a-- );
```

Comment: This really is circular reasoning.  You indented the first snippet that way because `?:` is right-to-left associative.  It doesn't become right-to-left associative because of your indentation.  IOW, the indentation isn't "why" it has a particular meaning.

Answer (score 11):

[Operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_precedence) and [associativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity)

[Table of operator precedence and associativity for C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence)

Answer (score 0):

Also, please note that these (horrible) expressions are deterministic *only* because the ?: operator is used. This operator is one of the very few operators in the C language where the *order of evaluation* is actually specified. Had you written some other abomination like `i++ + ++i;` then the compiler could have evaluated the left operand or the right operand first, which it picks is not defined in the C language.

As a rule of thumb, never use the ++ operator as part of an expression with other operators. Only use it on a line of its own (or as loop iterator). Because, against mainstream belief, there is actually never a reason to use it together with other operators.